# emacs ps-print-buffer command chinese character error mac os

Tags: emacs

I have written chinese characters in the comments of erlang's source code. 
The operation system is mac os lion. 
The emacs's version is 23.3.1. 
In emacs, the chinese's character's can be shown correctly. But when printing(ps-print-buffer), all chinese characters become '???'. But the MS word's print function is ok. 
Is this print driver's problem or emacs's problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a limitation in Emacs's ps-print package, because it does not know how to map those characters to Postscript commands (I cannot remember the details, but IIRC this mapping is not completely trivial for reasons that escape me).